# How to construct a product set whose complement is not a product set?

Tags: general-topology

How to construct a product set whose complement is not a product set ?

In this question, the product set is arbitrary set of the n-ary Cartesian product over n sets X1, ..., Xn, that is,

[image]

Comment: Hint: use $[0,1]^2$ in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: I'd like to see a product set, with a complement that is a product. - of course there is the trivial case where either the set or the complement is empty, but apart from that?

Answer (score 2):

This is not strictly answering the question, but some people have wondered about whether it's possible to construct a product set whose complement *is* a product set.  I think this is the best you can do.

Let $A,B\subset X$ be any two sets.

Form the set $A\times (B\times X)\subset X\times X\times X$.  This is a product of sets

Then it is easy to show that the complement
$$
(X\times X\times X)\setminus (A\times (B\times X)) = ((X\times X) \setminus (A\times B))\times X
$$

which is a product set.

Comment: Why not $A \times X \subset X \times X$ ?

Comment: @evilcube Henrik in the comments asked for examples where neither of the spaces was empty or the whole of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

If we consider only bi-products:
$$(A\times B)^c = A^c\times B\cup A\times B^c\cup A^c\times B^c,$$
so unless one of the sets $A,A^c,B,B^c$ is empty, the complement of the product set in *not* a product set.

However, as @Donkey_2009 showed in their answer, if we allow triple products, we can have nontrivial product sets whose complement is also a product set.

Answer (score 1):

A $\color{red}{\text{product set}}$ and $\color{blue}{\text{its complement}}$:

$$\begin{array}{|cc|}\hline
\color{blue}\bullet&\color{blue}\bullet\\
\color{red}{\bullet}&\color{blue}\bullet\\ \hline
\end{array}$$